# Динамическое изменение размера ListView

Tags: java, android

Суть проблемы така:  нужно отображать список строк количество оных изменяется, на фрагменте кроме listView есть еще элементы, как сделать, чтобы ListView занимала столько места на фрагменте, сколько строк на нее закинуто?

Comment: вам нужно показать разметку вашего контейнера, возможно установка по высоте wrap_content listView будет достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это решение помогло, просто создать свой ListView:
[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295080/android-wrap-content-is-not-working-with-listview)

public class MyListView extends ListView {

```
public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Установите размер `listView` `wrap_content`. Затем попробуйте добавить привязку следующего элемента к `listView`. В разметке к следующему элементу добавьте `android:layout_below="@+id/listView_id"`. Возможно, работает только с `RelativeLayout`.